# passing redux store in props coming as undefined?

Tags: arrays, node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom

When I am passing the store from `let store = createStore(myReducer);` in props to other component it is coming undefined. this is happening whenI am using `react-router-dom` but without that it is coming alright. 
The route part

the route is in `App` component

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Route path={"/layout"} component={Home} />
            <Route path={"/form"} component={UserForm} />
            <Route exact  path={"/"} component={this.layout}   />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter
```

layout method

```
  layout(){
    return (
        <Layout store={this.props.store} />
    );
  }
```

I am passing the store in the app component like this

```
const renderAll = () => {
    console.log("inside render all" ,store);
    ReactDOM.render(
      <App store={store} />,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
}
```

this store is going to body component from layout component like this

```
 <Body ChangeName={this.handleChangeName} store = { this.store}  s_key={this.state.inputkey} />
```

in body component I am fetching from from a api which is running in the node.js server in the `componentWillMount()`

```
 fetch('/api/get/all',{
    headers : {
    'content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
 }).then((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      return res.json();
 }).then(users =>{
      this.store.dispatch({
        type :"FETCH_ALL",
        data : users
      })
      this.setState({
        user: users
      })
      // console.log(this.state.user);
 });
```

I am getting error in the `map` function

```
 {this.store.getState().user.map(u => {
       return  <UserDiv name={u.name} age={u.age} location={u.location} gender={u.gender} job={u.job} />;
  })}
```

error

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

the weird part is when I am doing without the route it is coming alright
thanks in advance

Comment: Its  better to use react-redux library for this to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly in order to get the updated state from the store, you need to [**`subscribe`**](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#subscribe) to it like

```
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
    store.getState();
})
```

and hence it is not a React way to handle changes.

**Secondly,** when you are passing store to `Layout` component, it is entirely possible that you did not `bind` the `layout` function and hence `this.props.store` is undefined.

In order to use Redux the react way, you can make use of Provider and **[`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)** methods

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
const renderAll = () => {
    console.log("inside render all" ,store);
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
     </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
}
```

and then your Routes can simply be

and you can call `Body` component from `Layout` like

```
 <Body ChangeName={this.handleChangeName} s_key={this.state.inputkey} />
```

and connect the body component like

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   user: state.user
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Body)
```

Make sure to use the `connected Body component` in your Layout component.

After this you can use `user state` in `Body` component like

```
{this.props.user.map(u => {
       return  <UserDiv name={u.name} age={u.age} location={u.location} gender={u.gender} job={u.job} />;
})}
```

In case the user value is undefined in the redux store initially, you need to add a check in the Body component before using it like

```
{this.props.user && this.props.user.map(u => {
       return  <UserDiv name={u.name} age={u.age} location={u.location} gender={u.gender} job={u.job} />;
})}
```

Comment: I would make the changes you recommeded and one more thing whenever I am removing `app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/views/index.ejs'));
});` from the node.js server the react route is not working. Dont know why

Comment: since you use browserRouter, you need to server the index.ejs for any Route, so that client side Routes can take effect.

Comment: but then when I am keeping this my route below this are not working fine. they are giving wierd result

Comment: All your other routes need to be configured above it

Comment: I did that to then whenever I am giving any route it is going to "/" only

Comment: and one more thing how can the getState method be called when using react-redux cause we are using mapsstatetoprops and mapdispatchtoprops method but then how can we use the getState

Comment: you dont need to use getState in your components

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169491/discussion-between-aniketh-saha-and-shubham-khatri).