# Is it good practice to have just one subscriber at root level when writing a React/Redux application?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Last year I wrote a pretty sizeable application using React and Redux that had only one subscriber at the root level. The pattern was (roughly) as follows:

```
const myApp = () => {
  store.subscribe(render);

  render();
};

module.exports = myApp;

const render = () => {
  const rootDOMElement = document.getElementById('root');

  ReactDOM.render(

    <section className="myApp">
      ...
    </section>,
    rootDOMElement

  );
};
```

Essentially, I "rendered the whole thing every time", safe in the knowledge that React would on the whole only re-render the descendant components that actually needed to be re-rendered. This worked exceptionally well, even when the application scaled to thousands of component instances.

Now, however, I'm wondering whether this is sound advice to pass on to others. I have found no clear guidance (although admittedly I could have looked harder). Generally I get the impression that most people write many components that subscribe to the store these days. See, for example:

https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/6hperk/i_use_react_and_redux_but_never_reactredux_what/dj0fywb/

But isn't the whole idea of React, or at least one of the ideas, that you are not supposed to worry about what goes on under the hood? Subscribing at the root level works well precisely because React is smart enough to know not to re-render everything, right? Or am I missing the point? Again it's worth pointing out that my application ran exceptionally well, I never had to give performance a second thought.

Comment: with react, you would follow a react pattern and use connect and Provider with Redux. You might check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952857/passing-redux-store-in-props-coming-as-undefined/49952958#49952958

Answer (score 1):

When you creating app, its performance is not the only thing to think about. Besides many other, there is clarity and code obvious, ease of development and maintaining.

If you use connect function from react-redux it becomes completely clear to any who see your component what reducer and what attribute of that reducer will update that component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  status: PropTypes.number,
};

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div> { this.props.status } </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    status: state.someReducer.status,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Also it is important that you may use PropTypes for type checking of reducer values that pass to props, what facilitates component testing.

So I think, no. It is not good practice.
Good practice is to have so many subscribers, how many components should be subscribed to some reducers